# How to recognize file ending in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

I made a text editor with syntax highlighting support for Python. I have an Open file function and what it's supposed to do is recognize the filename extension and if it's .py, it will set the lexer to Python and everything else it will do nothing on. I opened a Python file but the Synatx Highlighting isn't working, what am I doing wrong?

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc
import os

class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.filename = ''
        self.dirname = ''

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 500))
        self.control = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_WORDWRAP)
        self.FileMenu(), self.Menu(), self.Binds()

    def FileMenu(self):
        self.filemenu = wx.Menu()
        self.open = self.filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "&Open", "Open file")

    def Menu(self):
        self.menu = wx.MenuBar()
        self.menu.Append(self.filemenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menu)

    def Binds(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Open, self.open)

    def Open(self, e):
        try:
            dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Select a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.FD_OPEN)
            if(dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK):
                self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
                self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
                self.wildcard = dlg.GetWildcard()
                if self.wildcard == ".py":
                    self.Python()
                else:
                    pass
                f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
                self.control.SetValue(f.read())
                f.close()
            dlg.Destroy()
        except:
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Error loading file", "Error", wx.ICON_ERROR)
            dlg.ShowModal()
            dlg.Destroy()

    def Python(self, e):
        self.lexer = self.control.SetLexer(stc.STC_LEX_PYTHON)
        self.control.SetKeyWords(0, " ".join(keyword.kwlist))
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_DEFAULT, 'fore:#000000')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_COMMENTLINE, 'fore:#008000')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_COMMENTBLOCK, 'fore:#008000')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_NUMBER, 'fore:#008080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_STRING, 'fore:#800080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_CHARACTER, 'fore:#800080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_WORD, 'fore:#000080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_TRIPLE, 'fore:#800080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_TRIPLEDOUBLE, 'fore:#800080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_CLASSNAME, 'fore:#0000FF')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_DEFNAME, 'fore:#008080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_OPERATOR, 'fore:#800000')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_IDENTIFIER, 'fore:#000000')

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Window(None, "Text Editor")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `self.wildcard` will be what you set it to be i.e. `*.*` and NOT the suffix of the file that you selected.
So you need a way to determine the suffix of the selected file. I suggest the `rsplit` function, using the last item, see below.
Secondly, the `Python` function is not fired by an `event` so `def Python(self, e):` should be `def Python(self):`
Lastly, you have not supplied `keyword.kwlist`. This will not show up as an error because you have wrapped the code in a `try ... except`, so it will fail quietly.
Try the following:

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc
import os

class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.filename = ''
        self.dirname = ''

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 500))
        self.control = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_WORDWRAP)
        self.FileMenu(), self.Menu(), self.Binds()

    def FileMenu(self):
        self.filemenu = wx.Menu()
        self.open = self.filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "&Open", "Open file")

    def Menu(self):
        self.menu = wx.MenuBar()
        self.menu.Append(self.filemenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menu)

    def Binds(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Open, self.open)

    def Open(self, e):
        try:
            dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Select a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.FD_OPEN)
            if(dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK):
                self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
                self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
                self.suffix = self.filename.rsplit('.')[-1]
                if self.suffix == "py":
                    self.Python()
                else:
                    pass
                f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
                self.control.SetValue(f.read())
                f.close()
            dlg.Destroy()
        except:
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Error loading file", "Error", wx.ICON_ERROR)
            dlg.ShowModal()
            dlg.Destroy()

    def Python(self):
        self.lexer = self.control.SetLexer(stc.STC_LEX_PYTHON)
        #self.control.SetKeyWords(0, " ".join(keyword.kwlist))
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_DEFAULT, 'fore:#000000')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_COMMENTLINE, 'fore:#008000')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_COMMENTBLOCK, 'fore:#008000')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_NUMBER, 'fore:#008080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_STRING, 'fore:#800080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_CHARACTER, 'fore:#800080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_WORD, 'fore:#000080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_TRIPLE, 'fore:#800080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_TRIPLEDOUBLE, 'fore:#800080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_CLASSNAME, 'fore:#0000FF')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_DEFNAME, 'fore:#008080')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_OPERATOR, 'fore:#800000')
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_P_IDENTIFIER, 'fore:#000000')

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Window(None, "Text Editor")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

N.B. When something fails `quietly` and it's in a `try` statement, remove the `try` to see the error.
If all else fails the most trustworthy debug tool remains the `print` command. Not only to enable you to print values of variables but also to print comments that can show a path through your code.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I noticed that when I open a file and whenever I press undo, the file is blank again and when I redo, the file is back. How do I fix this and make it so that when I open a file this doesn't happen?

Comment: What `undo` and `redo` are you referring to? If it's the right click options, I assume that they fire an event of somekind, which you would have to fire up the `Python` module again. To be fair it's a totally different question.